# How to make layout like facebook ? Using html css (flexbox)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend

I want to make a layout(like facebook) with following features:

1. Fixed/sticky header and No footer
2. 3 div, where `div1:div2:div3 = 1:2:1`
3. 3 scroll-bar to control each div...
   Scroll-1 and scroll-3 will be inside of div-1 and div-3 to control respective content, scroll-bar-2 will be in most right of the main body which will control content of div-2
4. Full fixed page , no extra scroll-bar , check adding lorem1000 in each div

Please help me to make this layout... Thanking you in advance

html code that i have written

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <h1>This is nav</h1>
    </nav>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">lorem1000</div>
        <div class="col-5">lorem1000</div>
        <div class="col-3">lorem1000</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me to make this layout... Thanking you in advance
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I see your photo about your idea, and I review your `html`

## use css grid

using `css grid` you write the code only in parent element :)

in this example `.row` that have 3 childs inside it

---

so now I use your name classes you write before (`.col-3`, `.col-5`)

and dividing the width into equal parts (`fr`), I put that the sidebars that kill 3 fractions of the screen, while the mainDiv kills 5 fractions ... so mainDiv is bigger than the SideBars.

it responsive, you can change the values of `fr` as you like (remember that the first value must be the same as the final one, and the middle value must be bigger than the sidebars)

```css
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 5fr 3fr;
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.row {
  gap: 0.5rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 5fr 3fr;
}

nav,
.row>div {
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 51, 255);
}

.col-3 {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <h1>This is nav</h1>
  </nav>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">sideBar</div>
    <div class="col-5">mainContent</div>
    <div class="col-3">sideBar</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ok. I will edit it now @j08691

Comment: @j08691 edited.

Comment: Thank you very much dear, It is working mostly...
But i need to fix the whole page and most right scroll-bar will control the content of center div...
i added lorem1000 in every div and 
according to you code the whole page is moving when most right scroll bar is scrolled.. I want to scroll only center div with most right scroll-bar and all the page will remain fixed..

The best example is layout of FACEBOOK.. Please check.. Thank you again..